# Reflection.Net: how to load dependencies?

Tags: c#, reflection, dependencies, add-on

I try to add an addons system to my Windows.Net application using Reflection; but it fails when there is addon with dependencie.
Addon class have to implement an interface 'IAddon' and to have an empty constructor.
 
Main program load the addon using Reflection:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Temp\TestAddon\Addon.dll");
Type t = assembly.GetType("Test.MyAddon");
ConstructorInfo ctor = t.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
IAddon addon= (IAddon) ctor.Invoke(new object[] { });
addon.StartAddon();
```

It works great when addon do not use dependencie.
But if my addon reference and use an another DLL (C:\Temp\TestAddon\MyTools.dll) that is saved near the addon in disk, it fails: 
*System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyTools.dll' or one of its dependencies.*

I do not wants to copy the addons DLL near my executable, how can i do to tell .Net runtime to search in "C:\Temp\TestAddon\" for any dependency?

Note that adding

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Temp\TestAddon\MyTools.dll");
```

do not change anything.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If *MyTools.dll* is located in the same directory as *Addon.dll*, all you need to do is call `Assembly.LoadFrom` instead of `Assembly.LoadFile` to make your code work. Otherwise, handling the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event is the way to go.

Comment: It's a pity @Andreas hasn't been around since 2010, I'd give you a bounty if I thought you'd care. Fly free you little Austrian genius.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options:

1. You can attach to `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` to help the CLR resolve the assembly.
2. You could look into isolating add-ins into their own `AppDomain` (see `System.AddIn` namespace and [this website](http://www.codeplex.com/clraddins)).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using an [Inversion Of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) container?  I use Castle Windsor with an external Boo file that lets me easily extend the applcation without having to recompile or worry about supplying dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to access the private *`Assembly.`**`_GetReferencedAssemblies()`***.

Although, the method *could* change in a future version of the .NET framework, it doesn't seem likely—ASP.NET heavily depends on it, though it's possible they could move it from `mscorlib` to `System.Web` which is the only assembly that I know of from where the method is referred to.

Answer (score 1):

Assembly.LoadFrom works well until I try to use a webService in my addon, I had had a "*Unable to cast object of type 'X' to type 'X'*" exception.

It's ugly, but i will use Assembly.LoadFile with the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve.

Thanks guys.